# What does `$iv` appended to a symbol mean in the IntelliJ debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ debug window, some variables have $iv appended to their name:

[image]

What is the information that IntelliJ is trying to convey? A quick look at the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-variables.html) did not bring the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems generated by Kotlin compiler for inline functions:

```
const val INLINE_FUN_VAR_SUFFIX = "\$iv"
```

That const is defined [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/416392bb740a2bf068f6e87f82713000c78ba55c/compiler/backend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/inline/inlineCodegenUtils.kt#L66) and used [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/debugger/evaluate/FrameVisitor.kt).